# GeoServer WMS / WMTS with Mapnik rendering backend

Tags: geoserver, wms, mapnik, geowebcache, wmts

I am going to migrate our current TileCache WMS-T server to a current and up to date GeoServer / GeoWebCache product. We use Mapnik as our rendering back end and I would love to keep it this way. I run several layers written in Mapniks proprietary XML-Styling language... Therefor it would be wise to keep that.

Has anyone done this so far?
My idea so far is to run a lightweight WMS Server in front of Mapnik and then use that server to feed my GeoServers Tile storage....

Any other ideas?

Comment: This is not an easy pair but you can check if Mapnik OGCserver project is alive https://github.com/mapnik/OGCServer. Perhaps easier than to make Mapnik to serve as WMS would be to use MapProxy with Mapnik as source http://mapproxy.org/docs/1.7.0/sources.html#mapnik.

Comment: @user30184 Hi, maybe you can put it as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to "proxy" WMS queries through to an alternative service, using the "[Cascading WMS](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html)" feature in GeoServer. It is essentially going to look like a store inside GeoServer, but it'll look like a part of GeoServer / GeoWebCache to external users.

That offers a few management advantages, but there are some limitations, given in the documentation page I linked to. It looks like those limitations shouldn't be a problem in your case, except perhaps the authentication issue if your Mapnik server has some authentication lock-down.